# Vagrant up automatically destroys VM and associated drivers

Tags: vvv-wordpress

I wanted to contribute to WordPress so I needed to install wordpress meta environment. I am installing VVV using this [link](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/installation/). I have already installed Oracle VM VirtualBox.

At first installation everything went fine and I was able to use the local.wordpress.test site. I made some tweaks and messed up this url. Unable to solve this, I decided to reiterate the entire installation of VVV. I ran "vagrant up" command, this time everything goes fine, until at last I receive this message

```
 ==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
    default:  * Restarting nginx nginx
    default:    ...done.
==> default: Running triggers after up...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:90:in `method_missing': undefined method `name=' for #<VagrantPlugins::Triggers::DSL:0x0000000003911268> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/andys/vagrant-local/Vagrantfile:525:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:11:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:11:in `fire!'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:52:in `block in fire_triggers'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:51:in `each'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:51:in `fire_triggers'
    from /home/andys/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:239:in `action_raw'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:208:in `block in action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:598:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:194:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:194:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.1/gems/vagrant-2.1.1/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Everything gets created initially, I can see an entry in VM VirtualBox as well. But at last this appears on my terminal and every progress done so far is deleted. I am stuck with this a complete day. I tried many possibilities and couldn't find a solution. Finally I decided to ask here.

I just want to complete my vagrant installation smoothly. Please help me to prevent **"vagrant up"** from auto destroying the created VM user.I would be very grateful and open to any suggestions.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by uninstalling vagrant hostmanager plugin:

vagrant plugin uninstall hostmanager

refer:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-in-vagrant-up/20177/5